# Multidimensional Array PHP echo problems

Tags: php

I've been looking through the other issues that people are having with echoing a value in a multidimensional array, and I'm having issues with my code.  I'm accessing an API, and eventually want to put values inside of a table.  This is what I'm doing first:

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init('https://apps.net-results.com/api/v2/rpc/server.php?Controller=Contact');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:pass');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    json_encode(
        array(
            'id' => uniqid(),
            'method' => 'getMultiple',
            'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
            'params' => array(
                'offset' => 0,
                'limit' => 50, // 10, 25, or 50
                'order_by' => 'contact_email_address', //'contact_email_address' or 'contact_id'
                'order_dir' => 'ASC', //'ASC' or 'DESC'
            )
        )
    )
);

$strResponse = curl_exec($ch);
$strCurlError = curl_error($ch);
if (!empty($strCurlError)) {
    //handle curl error
    echo "Curl Error<br />$strCurlError<br />";
} else {
    //check for bad user/pass
    if ($strResponse == "HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized: Your username name and/or password are invalid.") {
        //handle login error
        echo "Error<br />$strResponse<br />";
    } else {
        //successful call, check for api success or error
        $objResponse = json_decode($strResponse);
        if (property_exists($objResponse, 'error') && !is_null($objResponse->error)) {
            //handle error
            $intErrorCode = $objResponse->error->code;
            $strMessage = $objResponse->error->message;
            $strData = $objResponse->error->data;
            echo "Error<br />Code: $intErrorCode<br />Message: $strMessage<br />Data: $strData<br />";
        } else {
            //handle success
            echo "Success<br />";
            $objResult = $objResponse->result;
            $intTotalRecords = $objResult->totalRecords;
            echo "Total Records: $intTotalRecords<br />";
            $arrContacts = $objResult->results;
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($arrContacts);
            echo "<pre/>";
        }
    }
}
```

This returns:

Total Records: 8

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [contact_id] => 306247082
            [email_address] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [title] => 
            [bounce_status] => 
            [unsubscribe_status] => 
            [account_id] => 33494139
            [account] => Comcast Ip Services L.l.c.
            [address_1] => 
            [address_2] => 
            [country] => United States
            [state] => Pennsylvania
            [city] => Pittsburgh
            [postalcode] => 
            [work_phone] => 
            [home_phone] => 
            [fax] => 
            [create_date] => 2015-09-15T14:38:03+00:00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [contact_id] => 306830523
            [email_address] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [title] => 
            [bounce_status] => 
            [unsubscribe_status] => 
            [account_id] => 33495425
            [account] => COMCAST CABLE COMMUNICATIONS
            [address_1] => 
            [address_2] => 
            [country] => United States
            [state] => Colorado
            [city] => Boulder
            [postalcode] => 
            [work_phone] => 
            [home_phone] => 
            [fax] => 
            [create_date] => 2015-09-16T15:46:43+00:00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [contact_id] => 306999302
            [email_address] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [title] => 
            [bounce_status] => 
            [unsubscribe_status] => 
            [account_id] => 33536778
            [account] => LIQUID WEB INC.
            [address_1] => 
            [address_2] => 
            [country] => United States
            [state] => Oregon
            [city] => Portland
            [postalcode] => 
            [work_phone] => 
            [home_phone] => 
            [fax] => 
            [create_date] => 2015-09-16T22:59:14+00:00
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [contact_id] => 304689645
            [email_address] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [title] => 
            [bounce_status] => 
            [unsubscribe_status] => 
            [account_id] => 
            [account] => 
            [address_1] => 
            [address_2] => 
            [country] => -
            [state] => -
            [city] => -
            [postalcode] => 
            [lead_owner] => 
            [work_phone] => 
            [home_phone] => 
            [fax] => 
            [create_date] => 2015-09-11T19:53:21+00:00
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [contact_id] => 305707747
            [email_address] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [title] => 
            [bounce_status] => 
            [unsubscribe_status] => 
            [account_id] => 33456585
            [account] => 
            [address_1] => 
            [address_2] => 
            [country] => -
            [state] => -
            [city] => -
            [postalcode] => 
            [work_phone] => 
            [home_phone] => 
            [fax] => 
            [create_date] => 2015-09-14T14:55:18+00:00
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [contact_id] => 306389764
            [email_address] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [title] => 
            [bounce_status] => 
            [unsubscribe_status] => 
            [account_id] => 33456581
            [account] => -
            [address_1] => 
            [address_2] => 
            [country] => -
            [state] => -
            [city] => -
            [postalcode] => 
            [work_phone] => 
            [home_phone] => 
            [fax] => 
            [create_date] => 2015-09-15T19:11:49+00:00
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [contact_id] => 305707370
            [email_address] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] =>
            [title] => 
            [bounce_status] => 
            [unsubscribe_status] => 
            [account_id] => 33456585
            [account] => 
            [address_1] => 
            [address_2] => 
            [country] => -
            [state] => -
            [city] => -
            [postalcode] => 
            [work_phone] => 
            [home_phone] => 
            [fax] => 
            [create_date] => 2015-09-14T14:54:20+00:00
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [contact_id] => 305707549
            [email_address] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [title] => 
            [bounce_status] => 
            [unsubscribe_status] => 
            [account_id] => 33456585
            [account] => 
            [address_1] => 
            [address_2] => 
            [country] => -
            [state] => -
            [city] => -
            [postalcode] => 
            [work_phone] => 
            [home_phone] => 
            [fax] => 
            [create_date] => 2015-09-14T14:54:52+00:00
        )
)
```

I go on to try to add:

```
echo "Some string: {$arrContacts[0][contact_id]}";
```

This returns nothing.  Is there a declaration I'm missing?

Comment: `$arrContacts[0]->contact_id` (those are objects, not an arrays)

Comment: Thank you I didnt look hard enough in the forum.  Thanks!